# Estimating GPRS power consumption

Tags: power-consumption, gprs

I'm designing a telemetry station for air quality measurement. Right now, I'm trying to estimate the power consumptions of different hardware configurations, but I'm struggling with the GSM/GPRS module. Any idea on how to estimate it? I will be sending small amounts of data (~300 bytes) periodically (every second), but I can send bigger packets of data with less frequency if that lower the power consumption, not sure.

Any idea?

Comment: What does the datasheet for the module say?

Comment: Power consumption:
    sleep mode < 2.0mA ; idle mode < 7.0mA ; GSM transmission (avg): 350 mA ;  GSM transmission (peek): 2000mA

My question it's how can I estimate the time that's gonna take for the module to send those ~300 bytes.

Comment: Test a prototype is what you need to do and compare with your estimate, then correct your assumptions.

Comment: Yes, I think I'm gonna need to do that. I was wondering if there was like a rule of thumb to estimate the power consumption of a comunicacion module.

Comment: I think the transmission time varies based on network availability. Still, that wait should be rather short, especially for 300 bytes. It might take far longer to wake up the module and have it connect. Lowest power = completely power-down the radio, store those bytes for as long as you can, and wake up the radio as infrequently as possible. Consider compressing the data also. Finally, 3G support is [slated to end](https://www.taoglas.com/portfolio/3g-sunset/) "soon."